# Can't install some specific packages for python using pip

Tags: python, pip

Below is for pygame, but I get similar error in tensorflow, matplotlab, email etc...

```
C:\Users\Deep Raval>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/9c/78626be04e193c0624842090fe5555b3805c050dfaa81c8094d6441db2be/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\deep raval\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Deep Raval\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rswglmlp\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Deep Raval\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rswglmlp\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\Deep Raval\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rswglmlp\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip` uses the [Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/) to download Python modules.  None of the projects you mention currently (as of this writing) have `.whl` files available for Python 3.8 (they are all 3.7 or below), which is likely why you are getting errors.